# How do I set up a embedded MySQL client in Qt

Tags: linux, qt, embedded

I'm trying to set up my `embedded Linux` machine as a MySQL client, in order to connect to a external `MySQL` server (running on a remote machine). `sqlite` is not an option.

I understand, thanks to [Basile Starynkevitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7298110/romain-pokrzywka) that I have to use `libmysqlclient` (because that is the only library to run such a connection and dealing with the MySQL client/server protocol on the client side).

[Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html) stats that:

> You need the MySQL header files and as well as the shared library
>   libmysqlclient.so. Depending on your Linux distribution you may need
>   to install a package which is usually called "mysql-devel".

Did someone did this and can point out to the right package?

Comment: Consider using [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) in your case.

Comment: Why do you need to use the deprecated `libmysqld` (which won't be supported anymore)? You should explain that. Or why can't you start a `mysqld` process in your embedded Linux system?

Comment: If you need to connect to some *external* MySQL server (running on a *remote* machine) you have to use `libmysqlclient`; it is the only library knowing the protocol to connect to the *external* `mysqld`. In other words, you should **edit your question** to explain what do you mean by "external MySQL server" (since `libmysqld` don't use any *external* server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

1. Installing [MySQL](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/9454/) on my embedded Linux and tested it with

   ```
   mysql --host=1.2.3.4 --user=Foo --password=FooPass testdb
   ```

   When an MySQL server is runing on 1.2.3.4.
2. I recompiled Qt with the `-sql-mysql` option, so the new compiled version will include Qt MySQL plugin.
3. Test if Qt MySQL plugin is supported with the next code:

   ```
   QStringList driverslist =  QSqlDatabase::drivers();
   QString str;
   foreach (str, driverslist) { qDebug() << str }
   ```

   Expected output is:

   ```
   QMYSQL3
   QMYSQL
   ```
4. Test that driver loaded as expected with the next code:

   ```
   QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
   db.setHostName("1.2.3.4");
   db.setDatabaseName("TestDB");
   db.setUserName("Foo");
   db.setPassword("FooPass");

   bool ok = db.open();
   if(ok)
   {
       // "Connected"
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, assuming what you want to do is use the QtSql API to access a MySQL database without connecting to an external MySQL server. With the embedded server library, the server runs in the same process as your client Qt Application, similar to how SQLite works.

One caveat though: the libmysqld embedded server library is deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.17 and will be removed in MySQL 8.0. (as mentionned on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/libmysqld.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is confusing and seems contradictory.

Either you want to work with an *external* MySQL server, and that means that your application opens a ([tcp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) socket) connection to some remote machine running `mysqld`. Then you *have to* use `libmysqlclient` (because that is the only library to run such a connection and dealing with the [MySQL client/server protocol](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/client-server-protocol.html) on the client side).

If that `mysqld` server is running as a *different process* on the same *embedded Linux system* you should have some way to start it (probably as part of the `init` scripts on it). Then you still use a socket communication to it, and you still need `libmysqlclient`. A possible difference with a remote machine running `mysqld` might be (but I am not sure) the socket family. Perhaps `libmysqlclient` is using [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) sockets in the special case of connecting to a server on the same machine.

Or you don't want any external server. You might consider `libmysqld` but as [Romain answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41277557/841108) it is deprecated and is becoming unsupported (so I feel that would be a very bad choice). Then all the database code is running on your embedded Linux computer, which also has all the data storage. In that case (relational database & data & storage on the same *embedded Linux computer*), I would recommend using [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) instead because it is well supported and quite stable.

If your `mysqld` daemon is running on a remote machine you cannot (realistically) avoid `libmysqlclient` (otherwise you'll need to rewrite most of it).